# How to check if an object was initialized? Objective-C

Tags: objective-c

I'm wondering if there is  a way to check wether a variable that has been declared has been assigned or initialized or not in Objective C..

thank you

Answer (score 11, accepted):

All instances variables are set to 0 (or nil for objects) in the alloc method, see [The Objective-C Programming Language](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocObjectsClasses.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH11-TPXREF115).

This means you can check the variable with

```
if (!var) {...}
```

Be aware though that there is no way to differentiate between the state after initialization or just being set to 0.

Answer (score 7):

Check if the object is 'nil':

```
if(object == nil){ };
```